# want to delete oldest record when a new one is added leaving no more then 5 records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
id      user_id     message     timestamp
----    -------     --------    ----------
1        abc        message1    2015-07-27 19:10:40
2        def        message1    2015-07-27 19:20:41
3        xyz        message1    2015-07-27 19:30:41
4        abc        message2    2015-07-28 19:11:40
5        abc        message3    2015-07-28 19:12:40
6        abc        message4    2015-07-28 19:13:40
7        abc        message5    2015-07-28 19:14:40
```

When user 'abc' adds the 6th message I want the 1st one (oldest) to be deleted.

I'm trying the following two SQL queries but it only leaves 5 messages total not taking into account the user_id

```
INSERT INTO sample(user_id, message, created)
VALUES('abc', 'message6', now());

DELETE FROM sample 
WHERE user_id = 'abc' 
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                 FROM 
                     (SELECT id 
                      FROM sample 
                      ORDER BY id DESC 
                      LIMIT 5) x 
                );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use an UPDATE to update the  row with oldest date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack the selection of the user in your second query.

Also, as Jorge Campos underlines, you should order by date so that an edit/update of existing message is considered as a latest message and not an old one.

Try

```
INSERT INTO sample(user_id,message,created)
VALUES('abc','message6',now());

DELETE FROM sample WHERE user_id = 'abc' AND id NOT IN ( 
  SELECT id 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM sample WHERE user_id = 'abc'
    ORDER BY created DESC 
    LIMIT 5
    ) x 
  );
```

Comment: I would order it by date since an update could occur.